# Hyperledger Sawtooth Supply Chain transaction example in python

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, python-3.6, hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

I successfully built and ran the transaction processor for supply chain on ubuntu 16.04. Now I would like to create a client transaction using the python sdk. I referred to
https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/nightly/1-2/_autogen/sdk_submit_tutorial_python.html
and
https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/supply-chain/nightly/master/family_specification.html#transactions
as reference.

But so far the validator always rejects my transaction and calls it invalid. My TP is running correctly and is receiving the transaction but is unable to deserialize the payload.

Does anyone have an example script in python for creating a transaction? For example creating a new agent or fish?

Comment: Here is one easy to understand example client in Python https://github.com/danintel/sawtooth-cookiejar/tree/master/pyclient

Comment: I just realized we have to serialize our payload with proto for the supply-chain-tp. But I am now struggling to get the generated python class from proto (payload_pb2.py). In the supply chain repo  [link](https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-supply-chain/blob/master/tests/sawtooth_sc_test/supply_chain_message_factory.py)
the payload_pb2 file was imported. But I can't find or generate it.

Comment: you can generate proto class with shell
protoc -I=./ --python_out=./ proto_name.proto
or you can get a script here: 
https://github.com/hyperledger/education-sawtooth-simple-supply/blob/master/bin/simple-supply-protogen

Comment: follow the latest documentation instead of nighty
https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/app_developers_guide/ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works. I was able to generate the .proto files from https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-supply-chain/tree/master/protos for python. After installing the `supply-rest-api` the validator accepts my payload.